# Deploy mosaico app to web domain with grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, web-hosting, mosaico

However, I want to host this email editor - [Mosaico.io](https://mosaico.io/%20%22Mosaico.io), on my personal domain (hostagor, if it matters). It runs perfectly fine on my local server with **grunt**, but forgive my lack of experience and inability to find the right tutorials, I have no idea how to move it there.

I've been searching for 3 hours and have only found links only about how to deploy it to amazon s3 servers, nothing about a regular domain.

I do realize I'm going to get hated for being a noob and not being able to read thousands of lines of documentation properly, but in case there's anyone who can spend 5 minutes to get me on the right path (because most likely I'm googling the wrong terms), you'd be my savior.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a regular domain'? Skimming the code it looks like the majority of the app is client-side code, so can be hosted by any web server, but if you look at [backend](https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/tree/master/backend) in the source you can see it needs some server-side components too. There's a node.js implementation provided - can your host do node.js? - or you can probably reimplement these in a different language (PHP? Python?) depending on what your host provides for you. However the implementation here says you'll need a better version for production anyway.

Comment: @Rup I believe I need a host with node.js. After that I install grunt and repeat the same actions as on my local server. Is that correct or I'm missing something (no need for reimplementing in any other language)?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my node.js knowledge. You could use grunt, yes, provided you make sure it starts automatically on server start and is restarted if it crashes, then set up your web server to proxy some set of requests to the grunt port internally. But there are almost certainly better ways to host a node.js app - I'd guess grunt is only meant for development and testing.

Comment: You might want to e.g. look at [Heroku's node.js instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction). At first glance I can't tell if Mosaico would just work on Heroku or would need changes, but I'd guess they help you set up an app to run in production. Depending on usage you might even get away with hosting this on Heroku's free tier.